# What is going on in the lyrics of Kate Rusby's song “The Lark”?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, folk

What is going on in the [lyrics](http://www.songlyrics.com/kate-rusby/the-lark-lyrics/) of [Kate Rusby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Rusby)'s song [“The Lark”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db1IchkKpLw)?

This song is moving but cryptic—it's hard for me to tell what's going on. There may have been a breakup between the narrator and the person addressed in the chorus, a long time ago, though (maybe) the narrator still has feelings for the addressee—

> Time it is past now and I roam free,
>   Is it wrong to wish you still need me?

Is the narrator someone who's left their partner (temporarily at least), but feels lost and lonely and isolated without them?

> Out in the field where the lark it flies,
>   Over the earth where my heart it lies,
>   Oh how it sings when the west winds blow,
>   Out in the field where no-one goes.
>
> Oh how I'm cold will you let me in,
>   If you could hear me speak, where would I begin,
>   Time it is past now and I roam free,
>   Is it wrong to wish you still need me,
>   Is it wrong to wish you still need me.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to research the same question.  I thought perhaps the singer (as a man) was a dead soldier, or someone who committed suicide for a lost love.    His heart lies in a field where no one goes.  Only the lark flies to that area.  He is cold (dead) but time has past, his spirit can run free;  but his love cannot hear him speak.  Even if she could, he wouldnt know what to say...but he longs for her and wishes that she still needed him.
     Probably too morbid but it just has that quality about it...so....haunting.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of this is as follows:

It *seems* to be sung by a person who has died and is lamenting the fact that they can no longer communicate with a loved one.

> If you could here me speak , where would I begin

Infering that you can't hear dead people.

Also, if you look at the words in further verses:

> Out in the field where the lark it sings
>
> There I was waiting for all love brings
>
> There I stood and there I fell
>
> Out in the field that I know well
>
> Out in the field where the lark resides
>
> Here I'll remain where my heart can hide
>
> Only the lark and the west wind know
>
> I'm in this field where no-one goes

The line 'There I stood and there I fell' infers that the person 'stood' in battle and then 'fell' in battle

Maybe the line 'I'm here in this field where no-one goes' refers to the battlefield where the person fell. In rememberance, people would generally visit a graveyard not a battlefield.

Dead and lost loves are a recurring theme in folk music:

[She moved through the fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Moved_Through_the_Fair)

Comment: Oh, "She Moved through the Fair" is a very haunting song.

Answer (score 1):

There is no more to tell as what you are saying. I can't find anything cryptic at all. The song writer tells quite  clearly what she feels and what she means. Your analysis and interpretation  is absolut correct.

Some people will it interpret as a love song - others could adapt it to a bible text as the prodigal son or the song of songs. But this is not meant in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Or... It's a tree... There I stood and there I fell...a lament for lost nature...

Is it wrong to wish you still need me?

"If you could hear me speak where would I begin?"

Where would an ancient tree of some 500 years start?